# Cubic spline interpolation in Python from scratch

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing, numpy, computational-geometry

I implemented the cubic spline interpolation explained in
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation as a Python class. Of course, such an interpolation should exist already in some Python math libraries. However, this post is not about using an existing specific solution, but is rather about review of a code written *from scratch* that uses only standard functions.

Following the best practices, I protected my code with tests (I preferred doctest for this example). In this way, we are good to refactor now.

Could you please help my to improve the quality of the code? You may just share your overall feedback or suggest some improvements.

Thanks,
Ivan

**Code**: CubicSplineStruct.py

```py
"""
Natural cubic spline interpolation
Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation
To run doc tests: python -m doctest CubicSplineStruct.py

>>> cubicSplineStruct = CubicSplineStruct()
>>> cubicSplineStruct.m_n = 4
>>> cubicSplineStruct.m_xvalues =  [0.0, 10./3., 20./3., 10.]
>>> cubicSplineStruct.computeYtoKMatrix()
>>> cubicSplineStruct.m_yvalues = [128., -64., 128., -64.]
>>> cubicSplineStruct.computeKCoeffs()
>>> print(cubicSplineStruct.interpolate(10./3.))
-64.0
>>> print(cubicSplineStruct.interpolate(5.))
32.0
>>> print(cubicSplineStruct.interpolate(20./3.))
128.0
"""

import numpy as np
from bisect import bisect_left

class CubicSplineStruct:
    """
    >>> cubicSplineStruct = CubicSplineStruct()
    >>> cubicSplineStruct.m_n = 3
    >>> cubicSplineStruct.m_xvalues =  [0., 10., 42.]
    >>> cubicSplineStruct.computeYtoKMatrix()
    >>> cubicSplineStruct.m_yvalues =   [100., 75., 95.]
    >>> cubicSplineStruct.computeKCoeffs()
    >>> y = cubicSplineStruct.interpolate(30.)
    """
    def __init__(self):
        """
        >>> cubicSplineStruct = CubicSplineStruct()
        >>> print(cubicSplineStruct.m_n)
        0
        >>> print(cubicSplineStruct.m_xvalues)
        []
        >>> print(cubicSplineStruct.m_yvalues)
        []
        >>> print(cubicSplineStruct.m_kMatrix)
        []
        >>> print(cubicSplineStruct.m_yMatrix)
        []
        >>> print(cubicSplineStruct.m_ytoKMatrix)
        []
        >>> print(cubicSplineStruct.m_kCoeffs)
        []
        """
        self.m_n = 0
        self.m_xvalues = []
        self.m_yvalues = []
        self.m_kMatrix = np.matrix(np.zeros(shape=(0,0)))
        self.m_yMatrix = np.matrix(np.zeros(shape=(0,0)))
        self.m_ytoKMatrix = np.matrix(np.zeros(shape=(0,0)))
        self.m_kCoeffs = []
        pass

    def pushFirstEquationToKMatrix(self, x0, x1):
        """
        >>> cubicSplineStruct = CubicSplineStruct()
        >>> cubicSplineStruct.m_kMatrix = np.matrix(np.zeros(shape=(1,5)))
        >>> cubicSplineStruct.pushFirstEquationToKMatrix(1.0, 1.5)
        >>> print(cubicSplineStruct.m_kMatrix[0, 0]) # 2./(x1 - x0)
        4.0
        >>> print(cubicSplineStruct.m_kMatrix[0, 1]) # 1./(x1 - x0)
        2.0
        """
        self.m_kMatrix[0, 0] = 2./(x1 - x0)
        self.m_kMatrix[0, 1] = 1./(x1 - x0)

    def pushLastEquationToKMatrix(self, xnm1, xn):
        """
        >>> cubicSplineStruct = CubicSplineStruct()
        >>> cubicSplineStruct.m_kMatrix = np.matrix(np.zeros(shape=(5,5)))
        >>> cubicSplineStruct.pushLastEquationToKMatrix(1.0, 1.5)
        >>> print(cubicSplineStruct.m_kMatrix[-1, -1]) # 2./(xn - xnm1)
        4.0
        >>> print(cubicSplineStruct.m_kMatrix[-1, -2]) # 1./(xn - xnm1)
        2.0
        """
        self.m_kMatrix[-1, -1] = 2./(xn - xnm1)
        self.m_kMatrix[-1, -2] = 1./(xn - xnm1)

    def pushMiddleEquationToKMatrix(self, i, xim1, xi, xip1):
        """
        >>> cubicSplineStruct = CubicSplineStruct()
        >>> cubicSplineStruct.m_kMatrix = np.matrix(np.zeros(shape=(4,5)))
        >>> cubicSplineStruct.pushMiddleEquationToKMatrix(3, 1.0, 1.5, 1.75)
        >>> print(cubicSplineStruct.m_kMatrix[3, 2]) # 1./(xi - xim1)
        2.0
        >>> print(cubicSplineStruct.m_kMatrix[3, 3]) # 2./(xi - xim1) + 2./(xip1 - xi)
        12.0
        >>> print(cubicSplineStruct.m_kMatrix[3, 4]) # 1./(xip1 - xi)
        4.0
        """
        self.m_kMatrix[i, i-1] = 1./(xi - xim1)
        self.m_kMatrix[i, i] = 2./(xi - xim1) + 2./(xip1 - xi)
        self.m_kMatrix[i, i + 1] = 1./(xip1 - xi)

    def computeKMatrix(self):
        """
        >>> cubicSplineStruct = CubicSplineStruct()
        >>> cubicSplineStruct.m_n = 4
        >>> cubicSplineStruct.m_xvalues = [1.0, 1.5, 1.75, 2.25]
        >>> cubicSplineStruct.computeKMatrix()
        >>> print(cubicSplineStruct.m_kMatrix)
        [[ 4.  2.  0.  0.]
         [ 2. 12.  4.  0.]
         [ 0.  4. 12.  2.]
         [ 0.  0.  2.  4.]]
        """
        self.m_kMatrix = np.matrix(np.zeros(shape=(self.m_n, self.m_n)))
        self.pushFirstEquationToKMatrix(self.m_xvalues[0], self.m_xvalues[1])
        for i in range(1, self.m_n-1):
            self.pushMiddleEquationToKMatrix(i, self.m_xvalues[i-1], self.m_xvalues[i], self.m_xvalues[i+1])
        self.pushLastEquationToKMatrix(self.m_xvalues[-2], self.m_xvalues[-1])

    def pushFirstEquationToYMatrix(self, x0, x1):
        """
        >>> cubicSplineStruct = CubicSplineStruct()
        >>> cubicSplineStruct.m_yMatrix = np.matrix(np.zeros(shape=(1,5)))
        >>> cubicSplineStruct.pushFirstEquationToYMatrix(1.0, 1.5)
        >>> print(cubicSplineStruct.m_yMatrix[0, 0]) # -3./(x1 - x0)**2
        -12.0
        >>> print(cubicSplineStruct.m_yMatrix[0, 1]) # 3./(x1 - x0)**2
        12.0
        """
        self.m_yMatrix[0, 0] = -3./(x1 - x0)**2
        self.m_yMatrix[0, 1] = 3./(x1 - x0)**2

    def pushLastEquationToYMatrix(self, xnm1, xn):
        """
        >>> cubicSplineStruct = CubicSplineStruct()
        >>> cubicSplineStruct.m_yMatrix = np.matrix(np.zeros(shape=(5,5)))
        >>> cubicSplineStruct.pushLastEquationToYMatrix(1.0, 1.5)
        >>> print(cubicSplineStruct.m_yMatrix[-1, -1]) # 3./(xn - xnm1)**2
        12.0
        >>> print(cubicSplineStruct.m_yMatrix[-1, -2]) # -3./(xn - xnm1)**2
        -12.0
        """
        self.m_yMatrix[-1, -1] = 3./(xn - xnm1)**2
        self.m_yMatrix[-1, -2] = -3./(xn - xnm1)**2


    def pushMiddleEquationToYMatrix(self, i, xim1, xi, xip1):
        """
        >>> cubicSplineStruct = CubicSplineStruct()
        >>> cubicSplineStruct.m_yMatrix = np.matrix(np.zeros(shape=(4,5)))
        >>> cubicSplineStruct.pushMiddleEquationToYMatrix(3, 1.0, 1.5, 1.75)
        >>> print(cubicSplineStruct.m_yMatrix[3, 2]) # -3./(xi - xim1)**2
        -12.0
        >>> print(cubicSplineStruct.m_yMatrix[3, 3]) # 3./(xi - xim1)**2 - 3./(xip1 - xi)**2
        -36.0
        >>> print(cubicSplineStruct.m_yMatrix[3, 4]) # 3./(xip1 - xi)**2
        48.0
        """
        self.m_yMatrix[i, i-1] = -3./(xi - xim1)**2
        self.m_yMatrix[i, i] = 3./(xi - xim1)**2 - 3./(xip1 - xi)**2
        self.m_yMatrix[i, i + 1] = 3./(xip1 - xi)**2

    def computeYMatrix(self):
        """
        >>> cubicSplineStruct = CubicSplineStruct()
        >>> cubicSplineStruct.m_n = 4
        >>> cubicSplineStruct.m_xvalues = [1.0, 1.5, 1.75, 2.25]
        >>> cubicSplineStruct.computeYMatrix()
        >>> print(cubicSplineStruct.m_yMatrix)
        [[-12.  12.   0.   0.]
         [-12. -36.  48.   0.]
         [  0. -48.  36.  12.]
         [  0.   0. -12.  12.]]
        """
        self.m_yMatrix = np.matrix(np.zeros(shape=(self.m_n, self.m_n)))
        self.pushFirstEquationToYMatrix(self.m_xvalues[0], self.m_xvalues[1])
        for i in range(1, self.m_n-1):
            self.pushMiddleEquationToYMatrix(i, self.m_xvalues[i-1], self.m_xvalues[i], self.m_xvalues[i+1])
        self.pushLastEquationToYMatrix(self.m_xvalues[-2], self.m_xvalues[-1])

    def computeYtoKMatrix(self):
        """
        Should be called when x knot values are updated

        >>> cubicSplineStruct = CubicSplineStruct()
        >>> cubicSplineStruct.m_n = 4
        >>> cubicSplineStruct.m_xvalues = [0.0, 10./3., 20./3., 10.]
        >>> cubicSplineStruct.computeYtoKMatrix()
        >>> print(cubicSplineStruct.m_ytoKMatrix)
        [[-0.38  0.48 -0.12  0.02]
         [-0.14 -0.06  0.24 -0.04]
         [ 0.04 -0.24  0.06  0.14]
         [-0.02  0.12 -0.48  0.38]]
        """
        self.computeKMatrix()
        self.computeYMatrix()
        self.m_ytoKMatrix = self.m_kMatrix.I*self.m_yMatrix

    def computeKCoeffs(self):
        """
        Should be called when y knot values are updated

        >>> cubicSplineStruct = CubicSplineStruct()
        >>> cubicSplineStruct.m_n = 2
        >>> cubicSplineStruct.m_ytoKMatrix = np.mat('1 2; 4 5')
        >>> cubicSplineStruct.m_yvalues =[3., 4.]
        >>> cubicSplineStruct.computeKCoeffs()
        >>> print(cubicSplineStruct.m_kCoeffs)
        [11.0, 32.0]
        """   
        kCoeffs = np.array(self.m_yvalues)*self.m_ytoKMatrix.T
        self.m_kCoeffs = [kCoeffs[0, i] for i in range(self.m_n)]

    def interpolateOnInterval(self, intervalIndex, x):
        """
        >>> cubicSplineStruct = CubicSplineStruct()
        >>> cubicSplineStruct.m_xvalues = [None, 10., 42.]
        >>> cubicSplineStruct.m_yvalues = [None, 128., -64.]
        >>> cubicSplineStruct.m_kCoeffs = [None, 2., 6.]
        >>> print(cubicSplineStruct.interpolateOnInterval(1, 10.))
        128.0
        >>> print(cubicSplineStruct.interpolateOnInterval(1, 18.))
        98.0
        >>> print(cubicSplineStruct.interpolateOnInterval(1, 34.))
        -58.0
        >>> print(cubicSplineStruct.interpolateOnInterval(1, 42.))
        -64.0
        """ 
        x1 = self.m_xvalues[intervalIndex]
        x2 = self.m_xvalues[intervalIndex+1]
        y1 = self.m_yvalues[intervalIndex]
        y2 = self.m_yvalues[intervalIndex+1]
        t = (x - x1)/(x2 - x1)
        a = computeACoeff(x1, x2, y1, y2, self.m_kCoeffs[intervalIndex])
        b = computeBCoeff(x1, x2, y1, y2, self.m_kCoeffs[intervalIndex+1])
        return (1-t)*y1 + t*y2 + t*(1-t)*(a*(1-t)+b*t)

    def interpolate(self, x):
        """
        >>> cubicSplineStruct = CubicSplineStruct()
        >>> cubicSplineStruct.m_xvalues = [None, 10., 42.]
        >>> cubicSplineStruct.m_yvalues = [None, 128., -64.]
        >>> cubicSplineStruct.m_kCoeffs = [None, 2., 6.]
        >>> cubicSplineStruct.interpolate(18.)
        98.0
        """
        if len(self.m_xvalues) == 0:
            return 0.

        intervalLowerBound = findLowerBound(self.m_xvalues, x)
        return self.interpolateOnInterval(intervalLowerBound, x)

def computeACoeff(x1, x2, y1, y2, k):
    """
    >>> print(computeACoeff( 10., 42., 128., -64., 2.))
    256.0
    """
    return k*(x2 - x1) - (y2 -y1)

def computeBCoeff(x1, x2, y1, y2, k):
    """
    >>> print(computeBCoeff(10., 42., 128., -64., 6.))
    -384.0
    """
    return -k*(x2 - x1) + (y2 -y1)

def findLowerBound(xvalues, x):
    """
    >>> findLowerBound([10., 30.], 9.)
    -1
    >>> findLowerBound([10., 30.], 10.)
    0
    >>> findLowerBound([10., 30.], 15.)
    0
    >>> findLowerBound([10., 30.], 30.)
    0
    >>> findLowerBound([10., 30.], 31.)
    1
    >>> findLowerBound([10., 30., 40.], 9.)
    -1
    >>> findLowerBound([10., 30., 40.], 10.)
    0
    >>> findLowerBound([10., 30., 40.], 15.)
    0
    >>> findLowerBound([10., 30., 40.], 30.)
    0
    >>> findLowerBound([10., 30., 40.], 40.)
    1
    >>> findLowerBound([10., 30., 40.], 41.)
    2
    """
    if xvalues[-1] == x:
        return len(xvalues) - 2

    left = bisect_left(xvalues, x)

    if left >= len(xvalues):
        return len(xvalues) - 1

    if (xvalues[left]==x):
        return 0 if left == 0 else left - 1

    return left - 1
```